# Мультиязычный сайт, переключение языка с помощью Cookies

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, cookie

Верстаю небольшой мультиязычный сайт (три языка). Решил сделать переключатель через куки. Но столкнулся с проблемой зацикливания в виду того, что скрипт отрабатывает при любом языке и идет постоянный редирект. Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить?
вот код:

```js
function getCookie(cookie_name) {
  var results = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
  if (results)
    return (unescape(results[2]));
  else
    return null;
}

function createCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain) {
  var cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) + ";";
  if (expires) {
    if (expires instanceof Date) {
      if (isNaN(expires.getTime()))
        expires = new Date();
    } else
      expires = new Date(new Date().getTime() + parseInt(expires) * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    cookie += "expires=" + expires.toGMTString() + ";";
  }
  if (path)
    cookie += "path=" + path + ";";
  if (domain)
    cookie += "domain=" + domain + ";";
  document.cookie = cookie;
}

function deleteCookie(name, path, domain) {
  if (getCookie(name))
    createCookie(name, "", -1, path, domain);
}

var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000); //куки на час

switch (getCookie("lang")) {
  case "en":
    {
      window.location.href = "index-en.html";
      break;
    }
  case "ua":
    {
      window.location.href = "index-ua.html";
      break;
    }
  case "de":
    {
      window.location.href = "index.html";
      break;
    }
  default:
    {
      break;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link_ua").click(function() {
    createCookie("lang", "ua", date);

  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link_en").click(function() {
    createCookie("lang", "en", date);
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#link_de").click(function() {
    createCookie("lang", "de", date);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Вы устанавливили куку, обновляете страницу. Срабатывает switch и делает редирект. Снова switch, редирект. И так по кругу.
Нужно логику работы скрипта менять. Редирект нужен только в случае, если язык в куке не соответствует отображаемой странице.

Answer (score 2):

`switch` отрабатывает при каждой загрузке и опять отправляет на новую загрузку.
Проще в обработчиках ссылок ставить куку и сразу отправлять юзера на нужную страницу.

```js
function handler(e){
  if(e.target.nodeName === 'A'){
    let lang = e.target.dataset.lang,
        view = document.querySelector('#result');
    
    // Внутри ставим куки и переход
    switch(lang){
      case 'ru':
        view.textContent = 'Выбран русский язык';
      break;
      case 'en':
        view.textContent = 'English is the selected language';
      break;
      case 'de':
        view.textContent = 'Ausgewählte Deutsch';
      break;
    }
    
    e.preventDefault();
  }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelector('.links').addEventListener('click', handler);
});
```

```html
<h4>Choose your language</h4>
<div class='links'>
  <a href='#' data-lang='ru'>Русский</a>
  <a href='#' data-lang='en'>English</a>
  <a href='#' data-lang='de'>Deutsch</a>
</div><br />
<div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Куки используйте для редиректов и шаблонизации на стороне сервера или хранения состояния, но переключение не стоит осуществлять клиентским редиректом. Если есть желание именно выбирать файл, сгенерированый на сервере заранее, обратите внимание как мультиязычность реализована в [статических генераторах сайтов](https://www.staticgen.com/).

Второй вариант, раз вы уже пишете скрипты - примените шаблонизацию на клиенте. В самом простом случае это [ES6 интерполяция](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings). Для сборки такого приложения используйте [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) + [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Это позволит импортировать прямо прямо в код скрипта как *json* лэнгфайл, вида:

```
"ru_RU" : {
   "HEADER_TITLE" : "Заголовок"
},
...
```

, так и любые типы шаблонов: [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/), [Jsx](https://jsx.github.io/), etc, с помощью `import`:

```
import './styles/index.sass'
import template from './templates/main.jade'
import languages from './languages.json'
import getCookies from './getcookies'    

const cookies = getCookies()

document.body.innerHTML = template( { l10n : languages[cookies.lang] } )
```

В шаблоне будет что-то вроде:

```
{ l10n['HEADER_TITLE'] }
```

Если текстов много, имеет смысл получать *json* [асинхронно](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) .